# Python3 create Daemon

Tags: python, python-3.x, daemon, python-daemon

I tried to create a Daemon in Python to run on an Ubuntu Server. The code below is the code I have problem with.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import logging
import logging.handlers

from daemon import runner

class Main(object):
    def run(self):
        my_logger = logging.getLogger('NameGeneratorDeamon')
        my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.0.69', 514),facility=LOG_DAEMON)
        my_logger.addHandler(handler)
        try:
            my_logger.info('Started')
            while True:
                pass
        except Exception as inst:
            #Send error to syslog server
            my_logger.critical(inst)

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/null'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
    def run(self):
        service = Main()
        service.run()

app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

The error message I got when I run the code is the following:

> ```
>    File "Main.py", line 35, in <module>
>      daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/daemon/runner.py", line 111, in __init__
>      self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'w+t')
> io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.
> ```

Does anyone know how to fix this, or do you have a better way to create a Daemon in Python?

Comment: How are you getting the error?

Comment: I run the command `Python3 main.py start`

Comment: Does it have to do with the fact that `/dev/null` is not seekable?

Comment: Maybe but how do I make it seekable?

Comment: Out of curiosity, try setting another `stdout_path`. See if it works;

Comment: Tested to change `self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'` but get the same error

Comment: Could it be some permission error or do i need to create a file in the dev folder?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this works with no errors:

```
# vi /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/daemon/runner.py 
# 118 -120
        self.daemon_context = DaemonContext()
        self.daemon_context.stdin = open(app.stdin_path, 'wb+',buffering=0)
        self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path,  'wb+',buffering=0)
        self.daemon_context.stderr = open(
                app.stderr_path, 'wb+', buffering=0)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer